# usestate can change the state value after axios in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I expected to get the url with category=business,but the web automatically reset my state to the url that dosent have the category.I dont know the reason behind

```
 let {id}=useParams()
 

     const [newsurl,setNewsurl]=useState(()=>{
        const initialstate="https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=c75d8c8ba2f1470bb24817af1ed669ee"
        return initialstate;})
      //console.log(id);
      const [articles, setActicles] = useState([]);
      useEffect( ()=>{
        
        if(id === 2)
          console.log("condition")
          setNewsurl("https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=de&category=business&apiKey=c75d8c8ba2f1470bb24817af1ed669ee")},[])  
       
        useEffect(() => {
          const getArticles = async () => {
            
            const res = await Axios.get(newsurl);
            setActicles(res.data.articles);
            console.log(res);
          };
          getArticles();
        }, []);
        useEffect(() => {
          console.log(newsurl)
     

         // Whatever else we want to do after the state ha
    
    s been updated.
       }, [newsurl])
    
      
                //return "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=c75d8c8ba2f1470bb24817af1ed669ee";}
     
      return (<><Newsnavbar />{articles?.map(({title,description,url,urlToImage,publishedAt,source})=>(
        <NewsItem 
    title={title} 
    desciption={description} 
    url={url} 
    urlToImage={urlToImage}
    publishedAt={publishedAt}
    source={source.name} /> 
))  } </>

  )
```

one more things is that when i save the code the page will change to have category but when i refresh it ,it change back to the inital state.Same case when typing the url with no id.May i know how to fix this and the reason behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the state in React acts like an async function.
Meaning that the when you set the state and put a `console.log` right after it, it will likely run before the state has actually finished updating.

You can instead, for example, use a `useEffect` hook that is dependant on the relevant state in-order to see that the state value actually gets updates as anticipated.

**Example:**

```js
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(newsurl)
   // Whatever else we want to do after the state has been updated.
}, [newsurl])
```

This `console.log` will run only after the state has finished changing and a render has occurred.

- Note: "newsurl" in the example is interchangeable with whatever other state piece you're dealing with.

Check the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) for more info about this.

Comment: thank for your respond i have there are difference on it which the first two log is without category and last with.But are there any reason behind this? And i one more things  is that when i save the code the page will change to have category but when i refresh it ,it change back to the inital state.Same case when typing the url with no id.May i know how to fix this and the reason behind?

Comment: A state in React is only held for the lifecycle of the component. Meaning that when the component is destroyed, that state is cleared. When you refresh the page, the component is destroyed as the entire app unmounts and re-mounts. The simple way to hold a state value between refreshes is by storing it in [`local storage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and reading from it when the component mounts.

Comment: thx a lot for your explaination .i have a much more clear concept on it now

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is an async operation so in the first render both your `useEffetc`s run when your url is equal to the default value you pass to the `useState` hook. in the next render your url is changed but the second `useEffect` is not running anymore because you passed an empty array as it's dependency so it runs just once.
you can rewrite your code like the snippet below to solve the problem.

```
  const [articles, setActicles] = useState([]);
  const Id = props.id;

  useEffect(() => {
    const getArticles = async () => {
      const newsurl =
        Id === 2
          ? "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=de&category=business&apiKey=c75d8c8ba2f1470bb24817af1ed669ee"
          : "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=c75d8c8ba2f1470bb24817af1ed669ee";
      const res = await Axios.get(newsurl);
      setActicles(res.data.articles);
      console.log(res);
    };
    getArticles();
  }, []);
```